# Apache Camel: How do I achive a transactional route in Camel if I have a DB access in a route and then an FTP producer endpoint?

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel, rollback, transactional

My route:

```
from(jms:queue:xxx)
...
.process(_db_access__here_will_be_written_in_db)
...
.to(ftp:yyy)
```

The problem is, after the message will be read from a queue, the data will be written in the Database, but if the ftp endpoint producer failed to write a file in the directory, I get an error in the route but the changes in the DB will not be rollbacked.

> I want to commit the changes to DB only when the file will be
>   successfully written to ftp directory. How can I do that in my route?

Answer (score 0):

you are looking at [transacted client](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/transactional-client.html).

you also may add transacted if you are using camel-sql

```
sql:insert into tables value (id=:#myId)?transacted=true
```

Comment: Unfortunatly that is not that easy. "transacted=true" is useful only for a consumer and not for distributed XA Transaction Manager.

Comment: Hi, did you get solution for this?